# Creating semi-private urls for show action in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a small app, that allows users to create lists and within these lists they can add gifts that they want. So far its very similar to a ToDo list app.

I have three models:

`User` - Can have many Lists

`List` - Can have many gifts and belongs to User

`Gift` - Belongs to List

In my `List` model as well as storing the name of the list, Im also creating a unique string of letters and numbers and storing it as `shared_key` in the record. The code looks like this:

```
def create_unique_url
  begin
   self.shared_key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10)
  end while self.class.exists?(shared_key: shared_key)
end
```

and ideally I want the url to look something like this `app.com/public/long_string_shared_key_goes here`

My main ***Question*** is, how should do I go about setting up a route to access the record at this public address.

Should I create another controller called public and have a show method there? Or should I create a public action in my llist controller and somehow manually create a route to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just a matter of single action I'd not suggest to redefine the #to_param, since it might affect all of your existing functionality. Still a matter of taste, mostly

routes:

```
resources :lists, except: [ :show ]
get '/public/:shared_key' => 'lists#show'
```

controller:

```
def show
  @list = List.find_by(shared_key: params[:shared_key])
end
```

view:

```
link_to list.name, list_path(shared_key: list.shared_key)
```

Comment: That is good but I do still need the show action as when the person is logged in, they still need to have a slightly different show view.

Answer (score 0):

In you case i would just alter a little the showing of the list. First in the list model redefine the to_param method

```
    def to_param
      long_string_shared_key_goes #by default this was returning the id - example...to access show a list you had to navigate to /lists/:id
    end
```

Now you need to change the routes.rb

```
    match 'public/:long_string_shared_key_goes', to :'lists#show', via: [:get]
```

Now you just have to change some find methods (if you are accessing the lists with example list.find(params[:id] you now have to take in consideration that you dont have the id in the params, but you long_string_shared_key).

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: That looks goog however I still need te show action as when the user who owns the list views the list the view needs to look different.